# Проблема с Interlocked

Tags: c#

Изначально нужно было написать поочередный XOR элементов массива. При реализации через Interlocked.Exchange (нужно именно с помощью него) выдает отличительные результаты от Aggregate. Не могу никак понять почему Interlocked выдает один результат, когда реализации в Aggregate и однопоточном XOR выдают другой(одинаковый).

XOR Interlocked

```
    private static int ParallelXor(int[] data)
    {
        int result = data.First();

        Parallel.For(1, data.Length, (current) =>
        {

            Interlocked.Exchange(ref result, (result ^ data[current]));
        });

        return result;
    }
```

XOR Aggregate:

```
private static int ParallelXorAggregate(int[] data)
     => data.AsParallel().Aggregate((current, result) => current ^ result);
```

XOR однопоточный:

```
    static int TestXor(int[] list)
    {
        int result = list.First();
        for(int i = 1; i < list.Count(); i ++)
            result = result ^ list[i];

        return result;            
    }
```

Comment: Замените картинки на код текстом. Чтобы можно было скопировать его себе и потестить.

Comment: Стоит добавить код в виде текста, а не в виде картинок - это значительно повышает шанс ответа - желающим разобраться с проблемой не придется перепечатывать код вручную :)

Comment: Но вообще проблема в том,  что interlocked  гарантирует атомарность, но не отсутствие одновременного доступа. Вам нужен CompareExchange,  чтобы заменять текущий result именно на результат его xor со значением.

Comment: @PashaPash, я правильно понял, нужно переписать вот так `Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref result, (result ^ data[current]), result);`

Comment: Просто в таком случае всеравно некоректный результат.

Comment: Interlocked.CompareExchange тоже не дает атомарности. впрочем для вычисления важна не атомарность, а атомарность+очередность операции ^. оберните в lock и увидите. Да и Parallel тут только тормозит все

Comment: @vitidev, я понял, спасибо, это просто такая задача была в Parallel делать.